# VB Script to move files around based on date changed

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I am looking to write a VB script to keep a folder tidy up. The rules are:

- Check if any file was changed today
- If at least one file was changed today move all the files last changed 2 days ago to another folder

This is what I have so far:

```
strFolder = "c:\testdelete"
objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles
  If DateDiff("N",objFile.DateLastModified,Now()) > 4320 Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile),True  End if  Next
```

This however is not working.

Comment: It would be helpful to add any piece of code. Asking a question without even trying to fix the problem is not a good policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad.                
This is what I have to start.  It will delete the files in the folder that are older then the date specified, but I am not a VBS person, just getting started.  

`strFolder = "c:\testdelete" : Rem change the path
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
 Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
 For Each objFile In colFiles
 If DateDiff("N",objFile.DateLastModified,Now()) > 4320 Then
 objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile),True
 End if
 Next
`

Comment: debug the application and see if the values are being populated accordingly. Do you have any errors, what line exactly doesn't match what you expect. Is it `objFSO`, `colFiles`. Go line by line and check where do you first encounter your first problem.

Comment: The code above works to delete the files older then 4320 minutes but I need to include a conditional that first checks to see if there are any files in the folder with a date of "today" and then move the files older then 2 days to another folder.

I don't know how to include the conditional statement or the correct syntax for moving a file versus deleting a file.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the files in the folder while

- building a list of the files modified at least 2 days ago, and
- checking if a file was modified today.

Something like this should work:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oldFiles = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

today     = Date
threshold = Date - 1

fileModifiedToday = False
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  If f.DateLastModified >= today Then fileModifiedToday = True
  If f.DateLastModified < threshold Then oldFiles.Add f
Next

If fileModifiedToday Then
  For Each f In oldFiles
    f.Move "C:\other\folder\"
  Next
End If
```

Comment: +1 for tackling the problem (not playing around with the OT's misguided code), the `>=`, and the `f.Move`. One nit thou: Could you spend a variable for the volatile `Date` and initialize it once near the top?

Comment: +1 Ansgar, cool stuff, I like reading your code, it's innovative.  "...playing around with the OT's misguided code" - I more see it as, recondition their code to what they understand, obviously this code is copied and pasted from another location, but why teach them to reinvent the wheel rather than just give them the next steps they need. I've always seen it as assisted learning. To each their own :)

Answer (score 0):

So to compare the dates of the file and the current day you can utilize the `DateValue()` Function which returns only the date of the `DateTime` variable. Then you can utilize the MoveFile command which works like `objFSO.MoveFile(FileObject, DestinationFolder)`

```
Dim strFolder, Dest
On Error Resume Next 'Move to manual error handling. 
strFolder = "c:\testdelete"
Dest = "C:\testmove"
Dim objFSO, objFolder, colFiles, objFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)  
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files  
For Each objFile In colFiles  
  If DateValue(objFile.DateLastModified) = DateValue(Now) Then
    objFSO.MoveFile(objFile, Dest)
    if err.number <> 0 then msgbox "Destination does not exist"
    err.clear
  ElseIf DateDiff("N",objFile.DateLastModified,Now()) > 4320 Then       
    objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile,True)
    if err.number <> 0 then msgbox "Unable to delete file"
    err.clear
  End if  
Next
```